# Can I somehow assign functions of an class to an object in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, class, local-storage

I have the class order

```
export class Order {
    constructor(public sName: string, public sSurname: string){}
   
    getFullName(){
       return this.sName + ' ' + this.sSurname;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I store the object of type `Order` in the localstorage and then try to retrieve that object, the information that the object is of type `Order` is lost when refreshing the page, that is why I cannot call the function `getFullName()` although the information are the same. In reality the class is much bigger and I dont want to create a new instance with `new Order()` when retrieving the object. I wrote a function `adapt(order: any): Order` but in this case I expect data from the database where the properties have different names (e.g. `Name` instead of `sName`. I could write a function `adapt2(order): Order` for the object with different property-names which I am trying to avoid. What would you recommend me to do?

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.order = this.localstorage.retrieve('order') // order.getFullName() is not known
    // should I write a new adapt function or would you recommend me to do something else?
}
```

Comment: how do you store the object ? show some code

Comment: @RachidO Hey, I use the ngx-webstorage, so I use the function ```store``` : ```this.localstorage.store('order', order)```. I know that the information is lost on refresh (asked this question already): I want to know how to tell the application that the object I am trying to retrieve is of type ```Order```. I could use ```new Order(order.sName ...)```but in reality the object is too big and I dont want to use it. That is why I am asking for other approaches.

Comment: that is expected. there is no option to store "classes instance" in any js storage. If you really need it, you'll have to implemet serializing and deserializing logic yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, since there is no standard way of serialising/deserialising classes in JavaScript. To solve this you could use the [typeson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeson) package to properly serialise the class. Or you could do something simple like this:

```
const order = this.localStorage.retreive('order');
Object.setPrototypeOf(order, Order.prototype);
```

Bear in mind though, if your class has any properties that are *also* classes, you will need to do the same for them recursively. That's why it is sometimes easier to use a package like `typeson`

Comment: ```Object.setPrototypeOf``` is exactly what I needed! Thank you!